# Linuxで大量のファイルをディレクトリ構造を維持したままコピーしたい

Tags: linux, command-line

`source_dir` 配下にある `*.x` というファイル（同じディレクトリ階層には `*.y` とか違う拡張子のファイルがあるがそれらを除いて）を、ディレクトリ構造を維持したまま `destnation_dir` にコピーするには、

```
cd source_dir/
cp --parent */*/*.x   destnation_dir/
```

のようにすると実現できます。

しかしながら、`*.x` がたくさんあるとコマンドラインサイズオーバーでエラーになってしまいます。そのような場合、どうするのがいいのでしょうか？

例えば、

```
cd source_dir/
find . -name "*.x" | xargs tar cf - | tar xf - -C destnation_dir/
```

のようにしてもできるようですが。

Comment: `rsync`で`exclude`オプションを使うのは駄目でしょうか？

Comment: find + cp コマンドで処理するとすれば `find . -type f -name '*.x' -exec cp --parents --preserve=all -t destnation_dir {} \+` でしょうかね。

Answer (score 2):

特定条件のファイルを相対パスを維持してコピーをしたい場合、`find`(1) でコピー対象のファイル名を抽出して `cpio`(1) でアーカイブ化、`cpio`(1) で展開するのがよいです。

例:

```
$ (
    cd /path/to/src/dir && find . -type f -name '*.x' -print0 |cpio -o0
  ) \
  |(
    cd /path/to/dst/dir && cpio -id
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

コメントで`rsyncのexcludeオプション、と書かれていますが、includeの書き間違いだと思います。ということで、rsyncにはコピーする対象をincludeオプションで絞り込むことができます。ただ、ディレクトリを再帰的にコピーする時には若干ややこしく、

```
rsync -a --include='*/' --include='*.x' --exclude='*' src/ dst
```

こんな感じで指定する必要があります。

tarでxargs使うのもいいですが、`--files-from`オプションを使うと対象にするパスのリストをファイルで指定できます。

```
cd source_dir/
find . -name "*.x" | tar cf - --files-from - | tar xf - -C destnation_dir/
```

xargsを必要とするほど大量にファイルがあるなら、tarで直接リストを読ませた方が効率的だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

[GNU install](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/gnumaniak/man1/install.1.html) コマンドはどうでしょうか。`cp` コマンドと似ていますが、`-D` オプションを指定することで移動元のディレクトリ階層を自動的に作成してくれます。

```
$ find source_dir -name \*.x | xargs -I '{}' install -vD '{}' 'destnation_dir/{}'
```

上記コマンド例ではファイル属性（更新日、アクセス権など）のコピーは考慮していません。適宜オプションを追加してください